# Typescript Generics with ordered array / tuples

Tags: typescript, generics, generic-list

I have a function, which takes 2 parameters:

1. a list of object keys
2. a function which has a single parameter: the value for the object keys

It doesn't matter, if the inner function gets the values in form of an array:

```
myFunction<T>(params: (keyof T)[], innerFn: (T[keyof T][]) => any)
```

Or as an object:

```
myFunction<T>(params: (keyof T)[], innerFn: ({[key in keyof T]: T[key]}) => any)
```

As long as the typing works `;-)`

**Those two function signatures of course don't work as expected.**

Here are some examples of how I'd like to use them:

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
    baz: boolean[];
}

myFunction<MyInterface>(
    ['foo'],
    ([foo]) => null    // foo should be typed as 'string'
);

myFunction<MyInterface>(
    ['abc'],    // should throw error, because there's no abc key in MyInterface
    ([abc]) => null
);

myFunction<MyInterface>(
    ['bar', 'baz'],
    ([bar, baz]) => null  // bar should be typed as 'number', baz as 'boolean[]'
);
```

The function signature should:

1. restrict the `params` array according to the provided `MyInterface`
2. correctly type the `innerFn` according to the `params` array

Is this possible using TypeScript?

If `yes`: How can this be achieved?

Comment: That syntax you are trying to use for parameters of 'inner function' is called [array destructuring](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html#array-patterns-work-with-iterables), it's part of javascript, not specific to typescript, **and the names you use inside [] do not matter**. Array elements are associated positionally with any   names that you chose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something similar to what you want, with a few caveats:

#### You'll have to break up your function into several:

The generic type parameter `T` needs to be specified explicitly by the caller, but the function arguments also need to be generic (e.g., `A extends keyof T`).  You can't have a function with parameters like `<T, A, B>` where `T` needs to be manually specified but `A` and `B` need to be inferred from the arguments.  You essentially get [all or nothing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20122) from type parameter inference.  One way to work around this is to use a [curried function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) where `myFunction<T>()` returns another function with `<A, B>` as type parameters.  That is, change this:

```
// F<> is just a placeholder
declare myFunction<T, A, B>(args: [A, B], funcs: F<T,A,B>): void;
// specify everything, annoying
myFunction<MyInterface, 'foo', 'bar'>(['foo', 'bar'], ([foo, bar])=>null);
// specify nothing, doesn't work
myFunction(['foo', 'bar'], ([foo, bar])=>null); // error
```

to

```
myFunction<T>(): <A, B>(args: [A, B], funcs: F<T,A,B>) => void
myFunction<MyInterface>()(['foo','bar'], ([foo, bar])=>null); // works
```

You can see how it allows you to specify `MyInterface` in `myFunction<MyInterface>()` and allows the compiler to infer `A` and `B` in the subsequent call.

#### It's hard to get generic with [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple):

TypeScript lacks [variadic kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453), so it's not really possible to give a single signature to many functions which act on "tuples of any length".  You end up needing to work around this by providing [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function signatures which act on tuples of the specific lengths you care about.  The "simple" mapping of a tuple of keys of `T` to a tuple of corresponding values of `T`, which you'd like to represent as something like

```
declare myFunction<T,K extends keyof T>(
  keys: [...K], funcs: ([...T[K]]) => void): void;
```

ends up expanding out to

```
// one-tuple
declare myFunction<T, A extends keyof T>(
  keys: [A], funcs: ([T[A]) => void): void;
// two-tuple
declare myFunction<T, A extends keyof T, B extends keyof T>(
  keys: [A,B], funcs: ([T[A],T[B]) => void): void;
// three-tuple
declare myFunction<T, A extends keyof T, B extends keyof T, C extends keyof T>(
  keys: [A,B,C], funcs: ([T[A],T[B],T[C]) => void): void;
// et cetera
```

for as long as you can stand.

#### Putting it together:

So, let's curry and overload, like this:

```
declare function myFunction<T>(): {
  <A extends keyof T, B extends keyof T, C extends keyof T, D extends keyof T>(
    a: [A, B, C, D], f: (a: [T[A], T[B], T[C], T[D]]) => void
  ): void;
  <A extends keyof T, B extends keyof T, C extends keyof T>(
    a: [A, B, C], f: (a: [T[A], T[B], T[C]]) => void
  ): void;
  <A extends keyof T, B extends keyof T>(
    a: [A, B], f: (a: [T[A], T[B]]) => void
  ): void;
  <A extends keyof T>(
    a: [A], f: (a: [T[A]]) => void
  ): void;
}
```

That handles tuples of up to length four.  Feel free to add more overloads if you care.  Let's see if it works:

```
myFunction<MyInterface>()(
  ['foo'], 
  ([foo]) => null    // foo is a string
);

myFunction<MyInterface>()(
  ['abc'],  //  error, '"abc"' is not '"foo" | "bar" | "baz"'.
  ([abc]) => null // error, abc is implicitly any
);

myFunction<MyInterface>()(
  ['bar', 'baz'],
  ([bar, baz]) => null  // bar is number, baz is boolean[]
);
```

Looks good!  Hope that helps; good luck.